# Class level method "undefined"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

With the code below:

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
  wrap_parameters :test, format: [:json, :xml], include: self.test_method

  def self.test_method
    [ :one, :two, :three ]
  end
end
```

I get a RoutingError:
`ActionController::RoutingError (undefined method 'test_method' for TestController:Class)`

I tried a number of different derivations of this, but nothing is working.

EDIT: `routes.rb` -- was routing to api.servername/create during error:

```
TestApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :subscriptions

  # API subdomain
  constraints subdomain: 'api' do
    get '/' => 'test#index'
    post '/create', to: 'test#create'
    get '/status', to: 'test#show'
  end

  # root route
  root to: 'pages#index'

  # User routes
  devise_scope :user do
    get 'login' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
    post 'login' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
    delete 'logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session

    get 'register' => 'devise/registrations#new', :as => :new_user_registration
    get 'profile' => 'devise/registrations#edit', :as => :edit_user_registration
    get 'users' => 'users/registrations#index'
  end
  devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions], controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations' }
end
```

Comment: Is it maybe because you define a method 'this_is_a_test' and try to reference it as 'test_method'?

Comment: Sorry about that! No, this is a simplification of my actual code and I missed that change. Fixed.